# Where is the Windows Application Experience service in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, services, windows-services

I'm having some file handle problems so I need to turn on the Windows Application Experience service, which is turned off by default.

I've tried

```
Run services.msc -> Application Experience
```

but the Application Experience service isn't on the list.

Where do I find it now?

Comment: It doesn't exist on any of the Windows 10 machines I have here, and since it was introduced with Windows 2003, I'm willing to bet it has been removed from 10.  To me, this smells of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), where you're asking about your supposed solution instead of asking about the actual ("file handles") problem you're having. Perhaps consider asking about that instead?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Do you have `AeLookupSvc`? It was in the technical preview.

Comment: @DavidPostill Not according to 'sc query'.

Comment: @Techie007 AeLookupSvc was the suggested solution for a problem I was having with Visual Studio Test Explorer not releasing file handles.  Since WAE no longer exists, I've implemented a workaround.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this works:

1. Search for **task scheduler**.
2. Select **Task scheduler library** in the left pane.
3. There select **Microsoft**.
4. There select **Windows**.
5. Then select **Application Experience**.

[Here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/where-can-i-find-application-experience-service-in/a499361b-b7c5-46d1-81c3-15a098860446?auth=1) is the link for your query.

Comment: But, may be it doesn't!